# Accepting std::array of char of any size as non type template parameter

Tags: c++, c++20, non-type-template-parameter

This is probably a weird use case, but I am trying to hack around the fact string literals can not be used as arguments to templates using `std::array<char, N>` as non template type parameter.

This works but with extreme limitation that all strings must be of same length(I could use `MAX_STR_LEN=100` or whatever and make all arrays that size, but that feels ugly...).

Is there a way to make [this code](https://godbolt.org/z/4YYevM) work so that different size `std::array`s can be accepted as template parameter?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <tuple>
#include <boost/mp11/algorithm.hpp>
#include <boost/mp11/tuple.hpp>
// I wish that this 6 is not fixed... but IDK how to fix it, maybe concept(IDK if concepts can be used as "types" on NTTP.
template <typename Type, std::array<char, 6> val_val>
struct TypeToValues
{
    using type = Type;
    static constexpr const char* val = val_val.data();
};

template <std::size_t Sz, std::size_t... Is>
constexpr std::array<char, Sz>
    arrayify(const char (&arr)[Sz], std::index_sequence<Is...>)
{
    return {{arr[Is]...}};
}

template <std::size_t Sz>
constexpr std::array<char, Sz> arrayify(const char (&arr)[Sz])
{
    return arrayify(arr, std::make_index_sequence<Sz>());
}
struct HelloType{

};
struct YoloType{

};
int main(){
    std::tuple<
    TypeToValues<HelloType, arrayify("Hello")>,
    TypeToValues<YoloType, arrayify("Yolo!")>> mapping;
    boost::mp11::tuple_for_each(mapping, []<typename T>(const T&){
        if constexpr(std::is_same_v<typename T::type, HelloType>){
            std::cout << "HelloType says: " << T::val << std::endl;;
        } 
        if constexpr(std::is_same_v<typename T::type, YoloType>){
            std::cout << "YoloType says: " << T::val << std::endl;;
        }
    });

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, why not use a requires requires clause?

```
template <typename Type, auto val_val>
    requires requires { { val_val.data() } -> std::same_as<char const*>; }
struct TypeToValues
{
    // ...
```

[Example](https://godbolt.org/z/ax7Pzd).

You could also write a constraint that only specifically `std::array<char, N>` satisfy:

```
template<class> constexpr bool is_array_of_char_v = false;
template<unsigned N> constexpr bool is_array_of_char_v<std::array<char, N>> = true;
template<class T> concept ArrayOfChar = requires { is_array_of_char_v<T>; };

template <typename Type, ArrayOfChar auto val_val>
struct TypeToValues
{
    // ...
```

But [that](https://godbolt.org/z/nP3P1c) feels excessively restrictive; you'll want to accept static string types in future.

Comment: In case anyone would care about this, I believe the official grammar is _"... a requires-expression as part of a requires-clause"_ rather than _"... a requires requires clause"_. This kind of nitpicking should generally be only tangentially relevant, but given the common confusion between requires-clauses and requires-expressions, it may be worth pointing out.